# Can't iterate over mongodb array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

We are looking for a user in the database by `'_id'`

```json
   "_id": "6381e7c6bf8892cf05c7c798",
    "username": "Teacher",
    "email": "teacher@gmail.com",
    "role": "teacher",
    "avatar": "fixtures/teacher.jpg",
    "token": "KNuSF7sscU3EJsMetUFKi",
    "authentication": true,
    "myCourses"
```

and

It is necessary to get a suitable object from the array using `'aggregate'`, which we find by the `'course'` field and change the `'status'` in it

```json
   "myCourses": [
        {
            "course": "6381e7c6bf8892cf05c7c7b3",
            "status": true,
            "_id": "6381e80f12d633b2e6c35fbd"
        },
        {
            "course": "6381edab4f212193837ab575",
            "status": true,
            "_id": "6381edc54f212193837ab57c"
        }
    ],
```

I have tried the following methods

```
const test = await User.find({ _id: userId, myCourses: {$elemMatch: {course: courseId}} })
```

```js
const test = await User.find(userId, { courseId: {$in : myCourses} })
```

```js
const updateCourseStatus = user.myCourses.find(elem => elem.course.toString() === courseId)
```

the last method works but I don't think it's correct

Comment: So you want to `update` a `status` in an element of the `myCourses` array?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but definitely an array that is located in the 'course' field

Comment: Something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dFw4lsO31Fu)?

Comment: Right! Only I don't know elem._id, I only have 'course'. I tried something like this but it didn't work https://mongoplayground.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update in myCourses course status.
Filter the document by `_id` and also the course you want to update by `courseId`.
Use pointer operator `$` to set value in pointed object property.
[Read the documentation here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

```
User.update({
  _id: userId,
  "myCourses.course": courseId
},
{
  $set: {
    "myCourses.$.status": newStatus
  }
})
```

[Try sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FvPVM0yAuXW)
[example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ytlJ8Yk4QVW)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to change `"status"` given `"myCourses.course"` using `"arrayFilters"` is:

```js
db.user.update({
  "_id": userId
},
{
  "$set": {
    "myCourses.$[elem].status": newStatus
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.course": courseId
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eLx9SgRYy80).